# How to get the multiple selected CollectionViewCell from the UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create a `xib file` and add a `Collection View Cell`. I add the progress bar in header file of cell like the following code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MobileVLCKit/VLCMediaThumbnailer.h"

@interface AITFileCell_grid : UICollectionViewCell <VLCMediaThumbnailerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *fileIcon;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fileName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fileSize;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *filePath ;

+ (NSString *)reuseIdentifier ;


@end

@interface AITFileCell_grid()
{
    BOOL fetching ;

@public
    UIProgressView *dlProgress;
    UILabel *dlProgressLabel;
}
@end
```

I also create another `xib file` and add the `Collection View` for loading `Collection View Cell`.

I want to selected multiple file and **hide the `progress bar` on each `cell` by `button`**.

But I can not get the cell when I click the delete button by following code.

```
- (IBAction) buttonCancel:(id)sender {

    if(self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems > 0){

        for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems){

            AITFileCell_grid *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AITFileCell_grid" forIndexPath:indexPath];

                //Hide the progress bar
                cell->dlProgressLabel.text = @"0%";
                cell->dlProgress.hidden = YES;
                cell->dlProgressLabel.hidden = YES;

        }
    }
        [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}
```

I set the breakpoint to the `cell->dlProgressLabel.text = @"0%";` , it show the `nil` in the log...and the progress bar didn't change anything.

But I can set the value to `cell->dlProgressLabel.text` and set value to `cell->dlProgress` in `NSTimer`.

Why the `cell` define in the `UIButton` seems not be efficient ?...

Can someone help and teach me how to solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dequeuing `Cell` by  doing

```
AITFileCell_grid *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AITFileCell_grid" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

which could be different from what you have been selected, instead get the selected cell from the collectionView

```
AITFileCell_grid *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath]
```